# How can I do 360 dunk in NBA 2k12?

Tags: xbox-360, nba2k12

I'm having trouble doing a dunk.

It says to turn the right stick 360 degrees, but it's not happening.

How can I do it? Is there any trick that's not made clear by the instructions given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It, unfortunately, takes practice. It may sound stupid for a game, but it's true. Also, you can't go any more or less than 360 degrees. Hope this helps!